# How to set HttpResponseMessage to return string thats not encoded in c#?

Tags: c#, http

In C# I have this in my api project

```
return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "error\r\n\r\nmessage");
```

But on the page, when it displays the message, it actually shows like

```
"error\r\n\r\nmessage"
```

when I want it to show like

```
error

message
```

(without the wrapping quotes too).

How can I do that?

Comment: Try with `error \\r \\n\r \\n message`

Comment: I am going to guess this is an html page? Then either return html or return json and format it correctly in the client making the call.

Comment: Im getting html code that has \r\n in it, in the server and when I send it to the client, it shows \r\n on the page.

Comment: Change the text to `"error<br /><br />message"`

Comment: Actually in my code, im getting that text from another http call. But also when the data returns, the html code is also wrapped with quotes on the client side. It looks like that createresponse code is encoding the data before sending it.

Comment: It might be, you are the only person that would know as you did not include much for anyone here to go off of...